# I'm trying to create a method within a class that will return a specific string but nothing is returned when I run the console app

Tags: c#

For more context, this is a text editor I'm trying to create. The purpose of entryBuilder is a stringbuilder that logs a user-inputted string so the method inserts text into the stringbuilder and a variable converts entryBuilder to a string so it can match the return type of the method.
The code is

```cs
string entry;
Console.Write("Where would you like to add text?: ");
int index = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
index = index - 1;
Console.Write("Input text you would like to add?: ");
string inputText = Console.ReadLine();
entry = entryBuilder.Insert(index, inputText, 1).ToString();
return entry;
```

Console does not output entry it just moves on.

The code in which this is called is

```cs
if (operationsIndex == "3" || operationsIndexString == "manually edit")
                {
                    Operation operation = new Operation();
                    operation.ManuallyEdit(entryBuilder);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
```

The whole class is

```cs
namespace TextEditor.Operations
{
    public class Operation
    {
    public string ManuallyEdit(StringBuilder entryBuilder)
        {
            int index;
            string entry;
            Console.Write("Where would you like to add text?: ");
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out index);
            index = index - 1;
            Console.Write("Input text you would like to add?: ");
            string inputText = Console.ReadLine();
            entry = entryBuilder.Insert(index, inputText, 1).ToString();
            return entry;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `entryBuilder`?

Comment: You need `Console.ReadLine()` or similar to prevent the code continuing execution.

Comment: Tip: Use `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: You need to show the class, method, and how you're calling it. Otherwise it's not possible to tell where your issue is.

Comment: Could you show us the entire method, including its definition, and definition of `entryBuilder`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't let the console to output the `entry`.

If you want to output the `entry`, you should call `Console.Write` before `ManuallyEdit()`:

```
if (operationsIndex == "3" || operationsIndexString == "manually edit")
{
    Operation operation = new Operation();
    Console.Write(operation.ManuallyEdit(entryBuilder));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```